# Activeadmin: create scope on boolean field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

In an activeadmin controller, I'd like to exclude from my index all Photos that have a boolean field called `is_private` set to `true`.

I'm unsure how to do this.

The code below gives me close to what I want:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Photo do
 scope ("public"){ |scope| scope.where(is_private: false) }
```

[image]

This creates a "public" button that I can press to filter out all the private photos. However, I'd like this filtering to happen automatically. I don't want a button to appear, and I want all the private photos to be hidden by default (for certain users).

How can I scope my photos on this boolean field (:is_private)?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is default filter to be set so here is what you need to do in your ActiveAdmin controller

```
  controller do
    before_filter only: :index do
      params[:q] = {is_private_eq: 0} if params[:commit].blank?
      # or this might work for you
      # params[:q] = {is_private: 0} if params[:commit].blank?
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solution starting from your code is setting the scope as the default scope:

```
scope ("public"){ |scope| scope.where(is_private: false) }, default: true
```

By this you have an option to list out all Photo objects or different scope.

Reference: [Active Admin docs](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can customize resource retrieval and default scopes 
http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html
so I'm suggesting next

```
ActiveAdmin.register Photo do
   controller do
    def scoped_collection
      super.where(is_private: false) 
    end
  end
end
```

This will hide private photos for all users.

Also you can add custom logic to `scoped_collection`

```
controller do
        def scoped_collection
          if user.super_admin?
             super
          else
             super.where(is_private: false) 
          end          
        end
      end
```

Also  ActiveAdmin gives you integration for such stuff as `pundit` and `cancan` out of the box

http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#using-the-cancan-adapter

http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#using-the-pundit-adapter

So now is good chance for you to start using authorization for such cases.